# Cannot find plugin "karma-ng-scenerio"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm

I am following along in a video tutorial "Learning AngularJS" by Jack Herrington that I purchased from packtpub.com.

I'm trying to demonstrate end-to-end testing after having run my first unit test with angular.

As per the instructions, I have added the following to the karma-e2e.conf.js:

```
    plugins: [
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-ng-scenerio'
],
```

When I type grunt test:e2e I get the following:

```
Running "karma:e2e" (karma) task
WARN [config]: urlRoot normalized to "/_karma_/"
WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-ng-scenerio".
Did you forget to install it ?
npm install karma-ng-scenerio --save-dev
Warning: No provider for "framework:ng-scenario"! (Resolving: framework:ng-cenario) Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Ok, no problem: I type

```
npm install karma-ng-scenerio --save-dev
```

Now I get this:

```
npm ERR! 404 404 Not Found: karma-ng-scenerio
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 'karma-ng-scenerio' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'testdemo'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
```

So I download the zip for karma-ng-scenario and issue this command and it looks like the problem is fixed!

```
npm install karma-ng-scenario-master\karma-ng-scenario-master --save-dev
karma-ng-scenario@0.1.0 node_modules\karma-ng-scenario
```

But now I type the command again and the same results

```
grunt test:e2e
```

and I get the same results!

```
Running "karma:e2e" (karma) task
WARN [config]: urlRoot normalized to "/_karma_/"
WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-ng-scenerio".
Did you forget to install it ?
npm install karma-ng-scenerio --save-dev
Warning: No provider for "framework:ng-scenario"! (Resolving: framework:ng-scenario) Use --force to continue.
```

What am I doing wrong?

I did some searching and found that ng-scenerio has been deprecated but should still work...

When I looked at the example at 
http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/ it did not appear to using nodejs or grunt and I found this confusing if indeed protractor is supposed to be a substitute for ng-scenerio.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple typo: you have `karma-ng-scenerio` (note, scen**e**rio instead of scen**a**rio) in your `karma-e2e.conf`. That is also why your first installation attempts failed. Fix that, and I believe everything regarding this should work.

Comment: Thanks! That helped. Now I have a different problem (I'm getting a stack trace). I guess I'll make a different post and reference this URL).