# How to add ANGULAR_SCENERIO_ADAPTER for end-to-end testing with karma

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, karma-runner

I'm trying to get my first end-to-end test to work with nodejs, yo, karma, angular, grunt and friends.

begin UPDATE Monday April 13 12:40

Thanks @naeramarth7: Since I see the updated web page does not require ANGULAR_SCENERIO and ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER I have removed them from the karma.conf.js file and now I am back to the earlier error:

You need to include some adapter that implements ___karma____.start method!

Any hints/suggestions?

end UPDATE Monday April 13 12:40

Please see [Cannot find plugin "karma-ng-scenerio"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598266/cannot-find-plugin-karma-ng-scenerio) for a little history.
I fixed my typo and was receiving another error message about a missing ____karma___.start function. After some google searching I added ANGULAR_SCENERIO and ANGULAR_SCENERIO_ADAPTER (as per http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/files.html) to my karma.conf.js like so:

```
files: [
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/e2e/**/*.js'
],
```

I am now getting a stack trace (see below). I tried google searching to better understand what I need to install and no luck.

Thanks

Siegfried

```
grunt test:e2e
Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 1 path cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "concurrent:test" (concurrent) task

Running "copy:styles" (copy) task
Copied 1 file

Done, without errors.

Running "autoprefixer:server" (autoprefixer) task
>> 1 autoprefixed stylesheet created.

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
>> 1 autoprefixed stylesheet created.

Running "connect:test" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://localhost:9001

Running "karma:e2e" (karma) task
ERROR [config]: Error in config file!
 [ReferenceError: ANGULAR_SCENARIO is not defined]
ReferenceError: ANGULAR_SCENARIO is not defined
    at module.exports (C:\code\testDemo\test\karma-e2e.conf.js:21:7)
    at Object.parseConfig (C:\code\testDemo\node_modules\karma\lib\config.js:281:5)
    at Object.exports.start (C:\code\testDemo\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:286:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\code\testDemo\node_modules\grunt-karma\tasks\grunt-karma.js:125:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\code\testDemo\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:264:15)
    at Object.thisTask.fn (C:\code\testDemo\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:82:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\code\testDemo\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:301:30)
    at Task.runTaskFn (C:\code\testDemo\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:251:24)
    at Task.<anonymous> (C:\code\testDemo\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:300:12)
    at C:\code\testDemo\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:227:11
```

Answer (score 0):

As the title in the karma docs says it:

> Heads Up! You're viewing the docs for v0.8, an old version of Karma. v0.12 is the newest.

What you're looking for is [karma-runner/karma-ng-scenario](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-scenario) which needs to be added to the framework section. See [karma-ng-scenario#configuration](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-scenario#configuration) in the docs.

Comment: Thanks. See my update for the new error I am receiving.